# Iterating through object to add up all matching properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, comparison

I have a caml query which is going to return something like this in xml.

```
    ID      Title        Percentage
    7;#7    2       1.00000000000000
    7;#7    3       0.220000000000000
    7;#7    sub 1.1     0
    7;#7    4       0.140000000000000
    12;#12  7       0.670000000000000
    13;#13  6       0.700000000000000
```

I'll likely create an aray of objects for each item. Something like this:

```
var result = [{id:7,title:"2",percent:1.0},...,{id:13,title:"6",percent:0.7}]
```

How could I iterate through the `result` and add up all the percentages with the same ID so I end up with something like:

```
var total = [{id:7,percent:1.36,count:4},{id:12,percent:0.67,count:1},{id:13,percent:0.7,count:1}]
```

Or even if I could just get 
`percent/count = totalPercentage` so I end up with an object with just `{id:7,totalPercentage:0.325}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var percentages = {};

result.forEach(function (it) {
  var obj = percentages[it.id] = percentages[it.id] || {
    percent: 0, 
    count: 0, 
    id: it.id
  };
  obj.percent += Number(it.percent); // Casting to Number, in case percent comes as string
  obj.count++;
});
```

This creates an object, with ids as keys. Should you wish to convert it to an array:

```
total = Object.keys(percentages).map(function (it) {
  return percentages[it]
});
```

To get the average of the percentages, you can do this:

```
total = total.map(function(it) {
  return {
    id: it.id, 
    percent: it.percent / it.count
  };
});
```

Comment: I think it's working as intended, but each percentage is returning as NaN. The results object stores the percentages as string I guess. I tried parseFloat when creating the initial results array but that didn't work. This is how I implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/HXwt7/1/

Comment: @Batman That wouldn't explain it -- you'd get strings and not `NaN`. Any chance some `percent` fields are missing?

Comment: I don't think so. I logged the result and they weren't missing.

Comment: Does your answer do the division between the sum of the percentages / the count? I don't see where that happens in the code.

Comment: Hi @sabof, this is the data I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/ymtQs/ I use jquery to find z:row, then pick out the fields I need and create an object for each and push the object to an array. I've just been taking the parentID and the percentage.

Comment: @Batman I meant the value of `result`, that creates this problem.

Comment: I put a console.log(it.percent); right before you do obj.percent+= it.percent; and it logged as undefined;

Comment: The result date is using property "percentage", you were using "percent", my mistake, I should have noticed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the new object and iterate though the old one. You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/TSyE5/2/

```
var totalPercent = [],
    total = {},
    result = [{id:8,title:"3",percent:1.0},{id:7,title:"2",percent:1.0},{id:7,title:"2",percent:3.0},{id:13,title:"6",percent:0.7},{id:13,title:"6",percent:0.7},{id:13,title:"6",percent:0.7}];
$.each(result, function(){
    !(this.id in total) && (total[this.id] = {id:this.id, title:this.title, percent:0, count:0});
    total[this.id].percent += this.percent;
    total[this.id].count++;
});

$.each(total, function(i){
    total[i].percent = total[i].percent/total[i].count;
    totalPercent.push({id:total[i].id, percent:total[i].percent});
});
```

Comment: Yea I'm getting the same error as the above answer. Percent is returning as NaN. I tried throwing in parseFloat where ever there's a percent but that's not working.